# Fire analytics tag based on message event from window

Tags: javascript

I have some code that checks to see what event data is being passed back from two different media players. The first player sends back `play button clicked`, but the second player sends back the data I want but it's I have to parse it and read it to see if it matches `play` and `startPosition === 0`.

Wondering if there is a better way to check both the players to see what data is being passed in. What I have just feels dirty.

```
function handleWindowMessage (e) {
    var originalEventData = e.originalEvent.data;

    if (originalEventData === 'play button clicked') { 
        _gaq.push('_trackEvent', 'Video', 'Played');
    }

    try {
        var parsedData = JSON.parse(originalEventData).data;

        if (parsedData && parsedData[0] === 'play' && parsedData[1].startPosition === 0) {
            _gaq.push('_trackEvent', 'Video', 'Played');
        }
    } 
    catch (ignore) {}
    finally { return; }
}


$(window).on('message', handleWindowMessage);
```

Comment: This isn't really large enough for an entire review, but, you may not need to use `===` everywhere, most evaluations support `==`.